# Log history of entered numbers in a simple calculator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm working on an update for a simple calculator app. The update includes a history display. My problem is that when I'm typing a number, the Log Display is ignoring the first number but logs perfectly all the rest. "Example", if I type `1234567 + 1234` ...  the Log displays "234567 + 234". So the first number is never there when it should be.

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
{
    NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    NSRange range = [[display text] rangeOfString:@"."];

    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
        if ( ! ([digit isEqual:@"."] && (range.location != NSNotFound)))
        [display setText:[[display text]stringByAppendingString:digit]];
        self.logDisplay.text = [self.logDisplay.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", digit];

    } else {
        if ([digit isEqual:@"."]) {
            [display setText: @"0."];
        }
        else  {
            [display setText:digit];
        }
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're loosing first digit is that `if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {` returns false for the first time.

For the first press your variable `userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber` is `NO`, thus, not going to be logged. The second call of `digitPressed:` will have `userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;` and will log.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response! I have changed the first call to NO. Now when I enter a number, all the rest is gone. If I change the 1 call to YES then the LOG is perfect, but the Calculator makes nonsense.

Comment: So I need to change the first to NO and keep the second BOOL on yes??

Comment: you have several mistakes which you will definitely fix.))) Programming experience comes from this kind of mistakes.